# IBM I ISERIES AS400 CPYAUDJRNE

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am investigating our audit journals on the IBM I. and using the easiest command CPYAUDJRNE for this project. My set up looks good but when I look at the data regardless of the entry type the path name is in hex.. I need this because I'm looking specifically at ifs objects. What am I missing?

```
CPYAUDJRNE ENTTYP(AF) OUTFILE(mylib/QA1009) 
JRNRCV(*CURCHAIN) FROMTIME(09012020 '12:00:00')

 select copnm 
        from qa1009co 
        where cooTYP = '*DIR' or cootyp = '*STMF' ;
```

Comment: When I use DSPJRN THE JOESD (Entry Specific Data) is hex. This is where the path comes from in the CPYAUDJRNE.

Answer (score 2):

```
select cast(copnm as char(5002) ccsid 37)   
        from qa1009co 
        where cooTYP = '*DIR' or cootyp = '*STMF' ;
```

I was able to get it with a cast which I had tried before but i didn't use the ccsid(37). This works.